# Jest is not defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm currently making a react app with typescript, and I'm testing using react-testing-library. The app crashes with `ReferenceError: jest is not defined`. All of my tests pass though.

Previously, everything was working. The only thing that has changed is I reorganized a few files.

Code:

```
import { FormProps } from "../containers";

const onChange = jest.fn(); // The problem
const history: any = jest.fn();
const location: any = jest.fn();
const match: any = jest.fn();

const TestProps: FormProps = {
  onChange,
  history,
  location,
  match,
};

export default TestProps;
```

Comment: Is this code used in your app?  `jest` is defined as a global when tests are run using `Jest`, but otherwise it doesn't exist and should never be used in code run in the app.

Comment: No it's not, but I rewrote my tests to grab directly from this file instead of the index of the folder this is in, and everything works now. Thank you for your help

Comment: Cool, glad it's working

Answer (score 0):

The `jest` global is only ever defined during tests. It's added in by the Jest test runner.

As mentioned in the OP's comments, always make sure that any references to test-only globals such as `jest` only happen in *test* files. If your runtime code includes a reference to a `jest` global, then that'll crash at runtime because the Jest isn't being used to run your app.

If you're seeing crashes referring to a `jest` global then it means your *runtime* code is accidentally importing from *test* code. Makes sure runtime files never import anything with `jest` globals - even transitively (e.g. `App.tsx` importing `shared.ts` importing `tests.ts`, where `tests.ts` uses `jest`).